# ldapjs error when adding user

Tags: node.js, ldap

Doing testing on ldapjs => [ldapjs guide](http://ldapjs.org/guide.html).

I am at the part, where a new enry is being added to ldap, giving the command:

```
ldapadd -H ldap://localhost:1389 -x -D cn=root -w secret -f ./user.ldif
```

the user.ldif file is the following (see link)

```
dn: cn=ldapjs, ou=users, o=myhost
objectClass: unixUser
cn: ldapjs
shell: /bin/bash
description: Created via ldapadd
```

However when giving the 'add' command, I get:

```
adding new entry "cn=ldapjs, ou=users, o=myhost"
ldap_add: Operations error (1)
matched DN: ou=users, o=myhost
additional info: Cannot read property 'ldapjs' of undefined
```

I do not get the given error.
What is actually suppose to be done to fix this?
I did not find any information about this.

Comment: Also tried to add a new user named 'ldap', no help.

Comment: The added user was 'ldapjs'.

Comment: Do you have an objectClass `unixUser` defined in the directory server schema? I get the impression that the objectClass `unixuser` is expected to inherit from `posixAccount`.The error message you get is seriously crappy but it might mean that the objectClass is not known to server.

Comment: I am reading more about the LDAP (and/or OpenLDAP) to understand better. The ldapjs guide looked good, but seems like it is not explaining enough or leaves something critical out.

Comment: Not having the "unixUser" object defined in schema, may be the reason (so far such a thing is not done in the example, afaik). Still reading on schema/objectClass definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did more examples I found.
Modified the '/etc/ldap/ldap.conf' according to this [example](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch5/index.html#step1-slapd).
More specifically I tried modifying the 'ldap.conf'-file with only these schemas included (as in the example):

```
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
```

The rest does not seem to be (yet) relevant for the ldap.js test I am doing:

One of these schemas likely holds this 'unixUser' as a parent schema (or as an objectclass, included by inheritance).

Rebooted the 'slapd' service after the modifications to 'ldap.conf' (my bet it is needed, so didn't even try without reboot):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/slapd restart
```